# Rails route error switch local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes

I'm setting my new Rails website in more than one language, and I'm having problems with the routes. I'm following the instruction of the book 'Agile web development with Rails 4'.

The browser print me this error but I can see that routes are created correctly, so:
What am I doing wrong? (At the end of this message I'll attach all my routes)

**No route matches [POST] "/en/home"**

When I try putting the routes directly in the browser ("localhost:3000/en" OR "localhost:3000/es") everything works OK. The error prints only when I change my language's switcher. That's why I think the routes are correctly set, and I think is a problem of my switcher or the controller...?

This is the code in the application.html.rb (basically a switcher between languages):

```
<%= form_tag home_path, class: 'locale' do %>
<%= select_tag 'set_locale',
options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s),
onchange: 'this.form.submit()' %>
<%= submit_tag 'submit' %>
<%= javascript_tag "$('.locale input').hide()" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the configuration of my routes.rb file:

```
Group::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  scope '(:locale)' do
    resources :posts
    resources :contacts

    root "posts#home"
    get "/home" => "posts#home"
    get "/contact" => "contacts#new"

    # static pages
    get "/investment" => "contents#investment"
    get "/partner-with-us" => "contents#partner", as: "partner"
    get "/our-companies" => "contents#companies", as: "companies"
    get "/site-map" => "contents#sitemap", as: "sitemap"
    get "/terms-and-conditions" => "contents#terms", as: "terms"
    get "/privacy" => "contents#privacy"

  end
  end
```

This is a file created in /config/initializers/i18n.rb:

```
#encoding: utf-8
I18n.default_locale = :en

LANGUAGES = [
    ['English', 'en'],
    ["Espa&ntilde;ol".html_safe, 'es']
]
```

And finally, this is the code for my posts_controller.rb, because here is where I create an action "home" in order to put the last post in the home page:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def home
      if params[:set_locale]
          redirect_to home_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
      else
          @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc")
      end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `:method => :get` to your form, like this

```
<%= form_tag home_path, class: 'locale', :method => :get do %>
```

Comment: That was it. Can you explain me why I have to add the GET method? Thank you very much.

Comment: because form_tag by default generates a form with POST as http method and you only have a route for GET method so your form should have GET as a method